# Excel find and replace many functions with a range to a different function

Tags: excel

I currently have an excel sheet with many =AVERAGE(range) functions (different ranges each time) that I need to change to =AVERAGEIF(range,"<>0") to avoid counting 0s. Is there a way to find and replace all of them quickly? just removing all 0s makes the average function return `#!DIV/0` and this can't be graphed so it's not an option that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short macro will work on very simple formulas like:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A10)
```

It will **not** work on formulas like:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A10)+1
```

In a standard module enter:

```
Sub FormulaFixer()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, core As String, dq As String
    dq = Chr(34)
    
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.HasFormula Then
            s = r.Formula
            If Left(s, 9) = "=AVERAGE(" And Left(s, 11) <> "AVERAGEIF(" Then
                core = Mid(s, 10)
                core = Left(core, Len(core) - 1)
                r.Formula = "=AVERAGEIF((" & core & ")," & dq & "<>0" & dq & ")"
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

If you have more complex equations, the macro would need to be modified.